# Memory leaks in my program; is the destructor not getting called?

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, valgrind, destructor

I feel like I'm bashing my head on a brick wall here.

I'm not sure that the destructor is actually getting called. I'm using a priority_queue to hold a bunch of nodes. Each node has a member, m_grid, that is a 2D array of structs. This grid represents the only pointers I explicitly use in my program.

For some reason, I'm getting lots of leaks. Could you help me out?

Here's the destructor:

```
grid::~grid()
{
  for (int i = 0; i < m_width; i++)
  {
    delete[] m_grid[i];
    m_grid[i] = NULL;
  }

  delete[] m_grid;
  m_grid = NULL;
}
```

The assignment operator:

```
grid& grid::operator=(const grid& g)
{
  m_x_rad = g.m_x_rad;
  m_y_rad = g.m_y_rad;
  m_width = g.m_width;
  m_height = g.m_height;
  m_orientation = g.m_orientation;

  if (m_width != 0)
    m_grid = new cell* [m_width];

  // from left to right
  for (int i = 0; i < m_width; i++)
  {
    m_grid[i] = new cell [m_height];

    // from top to bottom
    for (int j = 0; j < m_height; j++)
    {
      m_grid[i][j].m_occupied = g.m_grid[i][j].m_occupied;
      m_grid[i][j].m_rad = g.m_grid[i][j].m_rad;
    }
  }

  return *this;
}
```

The assignment operator is similar and as-expected.
Finally, here's a bit of valgrind output (there's a lot, but it all concerns grid::setSize() or grid::operator=.

```
==13329== 200 (40 direct, 160 indirect) bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 25 of 166
==13329==    at 0x4C2E80F: operator new[](unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==13329==    by 0x4020C1: grid::operator=(grid const&) (grid.cpp:192)
==13329==    by 0x40A02E: node::operator=(node const&) (node.cpp:129)
==13329==    by 0x4075A6: __push_heap<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<node*, std::vector<node> >, long int, node, __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_comp_val<std::greater<node> > > (stl_heap.h:135)
==13329==    by 0x4075A6: push_heap<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<node*, std::vector<node> >, std::greater<node> > (stl_heap.h:199)
==13329==    by 0x4075A6: push (stl_queue.h:502)
==13329==    by 0x4075A6: aStarGraphSearch(basic_map const&, node&, std::unordered_map<int, basic_node, std::hash<int>, std::equal_to<int>, std::allocator<std::pair<int const, basic_node> > >&, std::priority_queue<node, std::vector<node, std::allocator<node> >, std::greater<node> >&) (main_functions.cpp:216)
==13329==    by 0x4088ED: search(int) (main_functions.cpp:706)
==13329==    by 0x401AAA: main (main.cpp:13)
```

I'm really struggling here. I didn't have these issues when I was using stack instead of priority queue. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Without a [mcve] no authoritative answer is possible, but it's very apparent that the copy constructor fails to destroy the existing dynamically-allocated class members, hence the memory leak.

Comment: `operator=` is allocating memory without deleting the old memory. Is this intentional?

Comment: If you are allowed to, use `std::vector<std::vector<cell>>` instead of `cell**` to capture the grid.

Comment: @GregKikola I don't know that I catch your meaning. When working with the priority queue, I create a new node which is equal to the top node. This invokes `operator=`, but I need to keep both the original and the copy.

Comment: @RSahu: Not even that; use a `std::vector<cell>` and an encapsulating type that overlays 2D indexing.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, yes. `using row_t = std::vector<cell>; using grid_t = std::vector<row_t>;`.

Comment: @RSahu: No, not that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't delete `m_grid` (and the arrays it contains) in your assignment operator.

Comment: If I delete `m_grid`, I'd no longer be able to access the grid later on... right?

Comment: @hockeysaint That's right. However if you don't delete it, you'll have a memory leak.

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood. Correct me if I'm wrong, but now I realize that pointing `m_grid` at a `new cell*` leaves behind whatever `m_grid` was pointing at.

I thought you meant that I should delete the newly-created `m_grid`.

Answer (score 0):

A call to the assignment operator doesn't automatically call the destructor first. You have to cleanup any memory already owned by the object, yourself, if you're going to replace it with new memory.

Assignment doesn't make a new object; it just modifies the object you've already got.

Comment: Sure, but something like `node top_node = frontier.top();` (where the frontier is my queue) should make `top_node` an exact copy of `frontier.top()`, as I understand it.

Comment: @hockeysaint: That doesn't call the assignment operator. It's an initialisation, not an assignment.